# Debounce function in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debouncing

Been looking for a debounce function or way to debounce in Jquery. The build up of animations can get super annoying. 
Heres the code:

```
function fade() {
    $('.media').hide();
    $('.media').fadeIn(2000);
}
var debounce = false;
function colorChange() {

    if (debounce) return;
    debounce = true;
    $('.centered').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.centered').fadeTo('fast', .25);
    });
    $('.centered').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.centered').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
}

 function colorChange2() {
    $('.centered2').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.centered2').fadeTo('fast', .25);
});
$('.centered2').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.centered2').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
}

function colorChange3() {
$('.centered3').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.centered3').fadeTo('fast', .25);
});
$('.centered3').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.centered3').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
}

function closerFade() {
    $('.closer').hide();
    $('.closer').fadeIn(2000);
}
```

I wrapped those all in $(document).ready(function() {

Is there way to debounce??

Comment: Do you just want to stop the animations?

Comment: Well when you hover your mouse over the pictures, it will start the animation. If you run it over a couple more times- the animations will build up.

Comment: Depending on what behavior you want, you will probably want to check out this https://api.jquery.com/finish/ it has different options for stopping animations, clearing them, or finishing them

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I don´t like the idea to include a library just for a debounce function. You can just do:

```
var debounce = null;
$('#input').on('keyup', function(e){
   clearTimeout(debounce );
   debounce = setTimeout(function(){
      $.ajax({url: 'someurl.jsp', data: {query: q}, type: 'GET'})
   }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I would just include underscore.js in my project and use the debounce function that it contains. It works great. I've used it in multiple projects.

http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

> **debounce_.debounce(function, wait, [immediate])**  Creates and returns a
>   new debounced version of the passed function which will postpone its
>   execution until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last
>   time it was invoked. Useful for implementing behavior that should only
>   happen after the input has stopped arriving. For example: rendering a
>   preview of a Markdown comment, recalculating a layout after the window
>   has stopped being resized, and so on.
>
> At the end of the wait interval, the function will be called with the
>   arguments that were passed most recently to the debounced function.
>
> Pass true for the immediate argument to cause debounce to trigger the
>   function on the leading instead of the trailing edge of the wait
>   interval. Useful in circumstances like preventing accidental
>   double-clicks on a "submit" button from firing a second time.
>
> ```
> var lazyLayout = _.debounce(calculateLayout, 300);
> $(window).resize(lazyLayout);
> ```

Comment: if debounce is the only functionality you need then definitely not recommending including the complete `_ ` library.

Comment: I personally don't think it makes sense to reinvent the wheel for something a team has already built, made readily available, and maintains as browsers are updated regularly. Not only that, but once you use underscore.js for one thing, you typically end up finding many other places to use this library. Additionally, underscore.js is not a very large library. In my opinion, the value/cost ration is heavily weighted towards value.